# PYTHON: XML iterar para obtener todos los hijos de un elemento

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, nodos

Tengo la siguiente estructura en XML (a continuación de la raíz) :

```
   <Otros>
      <OtroTexto codigo="Pedido">0000098947</OtroTexto>
      <OtroTexto codigo="NombreCliente">letra por 8.000.000 del 25-01-2017 pagadero con cheque</OtroTexto>
      <OtroTexto codigo="Vendedor">75 Agente 75</OtroTexto>
      <OtroTexto codigo="Bodega">BODEGA PRINCIPAL</OtroTexto>
      <OtroTexto codigo="FechaEntrega">09/09/2020</OtroTexto>
      <OtroTexto codigo="LugarEntrega">759</OtroTexto>
   </Otros>
```

Y deseo iterar e imprimir solamente el texto de OtroTexto de la siguiente manera:

```
Notas: 0000098947
Notas: Letra por 8.000.000 del 25-01-2017 pagadero con cheque 
Notas: 75 Agente 75 
Notas: BODEGA PRINCIPAL 
: etc...
Notas: 759
```

Quizás sea bueno, obtener también el atributo.-

He intentado varias cosas pero no me funcionan, este es el último intento realizado, pero solamente logré obtener la primea línea de notas:

```
tmp = doc.getElementsByTagName("Otros") 
try: 
   for o in tmp: 
      txt = o.getElementsByTagName("OtroTexto")[0].firstChild.nodeValue 
      print ("Notas: %s " % txt) 
except: 
   print ("Ignorando notas: no existen o archivo mal formado en tag Otros")
```

Su ayuda será bien apreciada, soy programador de la vieja escuela con 50 años y estoy aprendiendo python + xml

Agradezco de antemano su colaboración...

**AGREGO:**

Adjunto el XML casi completo (tengo que eliminar alguna info privada)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FacturaElectronica
   xsi:schemaLocation="https://cdn.comprobanteselectronicos.go.cr/xml-schemas/v4.3/facturaElectronica https://cdn.comprobanteselectronicos.go.cr/xml-schemas/v4.3/facturaElectronica"
   xmlns="https://cdn.comprobanteselectronicos.go.cr/xml-schemas/v4.3/facturaElectronica"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
   <Clave>50609092000310120144500100001010000020435101272452</Clave>
   <CodigoActividad>523912</CodigoActividad>
   <NumeroConsecutivo>00100001010000020435</NumeroConsecutivo>
   <FechaEmision>2020-09-09T14:07:09-06:00</FechaEmision>
   <Emisor>
      <Nombre>Nombre Emisor S.A.</Nombre>
      <Identificacion>
         <Tipo>02</Tipo>
         <Numero>310123456789</Numero>
      </Identificacion>
      </NombreComercial>
      <Ubicacion>
         <Provincia>4</Provincia>
         <Canton>03</Canton>
         <Distrito>06</Distrito>
         <Barrio>01</Barrio>
         <OtrasSenas>100 mts este la Valencia</OtrasSenas>
      </Ubicacion>
      <Telefono>
         <CodigoPais>506</CodigoPais>
         <NumTelefono>22699999</NumTelefono>
      </Telefono>
      <Fax>
         <CodigoPais>0</CodigoPais>
         <NumTelefono>0</NumTelefono>
      </Fax>
      <CorreoElectronico>alguien@emisor.com</CorreoElectronico>
   </Emisor>
   <Receptor>
      <Nombre>Nombre RECEPTOR S.A.</Nombre>
      <Identificacion>
         <Tipo>02</Tipo>
         <Numero>3007123456</Numero>
      </Identificacion>
      <Ubicacion>
         <Provincia>2</Provincia>
         <Canton>07</Canton>
         <Distrito>05</Distrito>
         <Barrio>01</Barrio>
         <OtrasSenas>100 - 100  SANTA BARBARA</OtrasSenas>
      </Ubicacion>
      <Telefono>
         <CodigoPais>506</CodigoPais>
         <NumTelefono>22699696</NumTelefono>
      </Telefono>
      <CorreoElectronico>alguno@gmail.com</CorreoElectronico>
   </Receptor>
   <CondicionVenta>02</CondicionVenta>
   <PlazoCredito>45</PlazoCredito>
   <MedioPago>99</MedioPago>
   <DetalleServicio>
      <LineaDetalle>
         <NumeroLinea>1</NumeroLinea>
         <Codigo>038290</Codigo>
         <CodigoComercial>
            <Tipo>01</Tipo>
            <Codigo>038290</Codigo>
         </CodigoComercial>
         <CodigoComercial>
            <Tipo>03</Tipo>
            <Codigo>7441152918448</Codigo>
         </CodigoComercial>
         <Cantidad>12.000</Cantidad>
         <UnidadMedida>Unid</UnidadMedida>
         <Detalle>LANZA 50 CMS SM.226-A CARPI</Detalle>
         <PrecioUnitario>3974.02740</PrecioUnitario>
         <MontoTotal>47688.32880</MontoTotal>
         <Descuento>
            <MontoDescuento>3338.18302</MontoDescuento>
            <NaturalezaDescuento>Descuento Comercial</NaturalezaDescuento>
         </Descuento>
         <SubTotal>44350.14578</SubTotal>
         <Impuesto>
            <Codigo>01</Codigo>
            <CodigoTarifa>02</CodigoTarifa>
            <Tarifa>1</Tarifa>
            <Monto>443.50146</Monto>
         </Impuesto>
         <ImpuestoNeto>443.50146</ImpuestoNeto>
         <MontoTotalLinea>44793.64724</MontoTotalLinea>
      </LineaDetalle>
      <LineaDetalle>
         <NumeroLinea>2</NumeroLinea>
         <Codigo>038440</Codigo>
         <CodigoComercial>
            <Tipo>01</Tipo>
            <Codigo>038440</Codigo>
         </CodigoComercial>
         <CodigoComercial>
            <Tipo>03</Tipo>
            <Codigo>7441152918523</Codigo>
         </CodigoComercial>
         <Cantidad>3.000</Cantidad>
         <UnidadMedida>Unid</UnidadMedida>
         <Detalle>MARCO PINTADO</Detalle>
         <PrecioUnitario>7595.50000</PrecioUnitario>
         <MontoTotal>22786.50000</MontoTotal>
         <Descuento>
            <MontoDescuento>1595.05500</MontoDescuento>
            <NaturalezaDescuento>Descuento Comercial</NaturalezaDescuento>
         </Descuento>
         <SubTotal>21191.44500</SubTotal>
         <Impuesto>
            <Codigo>01</Codigo>
            <CodigoTarifa>02</CodigoTarifa>
            <Tarifa>1</Tarifa>
            <Monto>211.91445</Monto>
         </Impuesto>
         <ImpuestoNeto>211.91445</ImpuestoNeto>
         <MontoTotalLinea>21403.35945</MontoTotalLinea>
      </LineaDetalle>
   </DetalleServicio>
   <ResumenFactura>
      <CodigoTipoMoneda>
         <CodigoMoneda>CRC</CodigoMoneda>
         <TipoCambio>1</TipoCambio>
      </CodigoTipoMoneda>
      <TotalServGravados>0.00000</TotalServGravados>
      <TotalServExentos>0.00000</TotalServExentos>
      <TotalServExonerado>0.00000</TotalServExonerado>
      <TotalMercanciasGravadas>70474.82880</TotalMercanciasGravadas>
      <TotalMercanciasExentas>0.00000</TotalMercanciasExentas>
      <TotalMercExonerada>0.00000</TotalMercExonerada>
      <TotalGravado>70474.82880</TotalGravado>
      <TotalExento>0.00000</TotalExento>
      <TotalExonerado>0.00000</TotalExonerado>
      <TotalVenta>70474.82880</TotalVenta>
      <TotalDescuentos>4933.23802</TotalDescuentos>
      <TotalVentaNeta>65541.59078</TotalVentaNeta>
      <TotalImpuesto>655.41591</TotalImpuesto>
      <TotalIVADevuelto>0.00000</TotalIVADevuelto>
      <TotalComprobante>66197.00669</TotalComprobante>
   </ResumenFactura>
   <Otros>
      <OtroTexto codigo="Pedido">0000098947</OtroTexto>
      <OtroTexto codigo="NombreCliente">letra por 8.000.000 del 25-01-2017 pagadero con cheque</OtroTexto>
      <OtroTexto codigo="Vendedor">75 Agente 75</OtroTexto>
      <OtroTexto codigo="Bodega">BODEGA PRINCIPAL</OtroTexto>
      <OtroTexto codigo="FechaEntrega">09/09/2020</OtroTexto>
      <OtroTexto codigo="LugarEntrega">759</OtroTexto>
   </Otros>
</FacturaElectronica>
```

Al final es donde están las notas del documento electrónico...

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor has el [tour] para hacerte a una idea de cómo funcionamos y consulta [ask]. En cuanto al código que muestras (ya que @Adrian te ofrece una respuesta bastante buena) sólo tengo una observación: El valor del atributo *codigo* **NombreCliente** no es consistente con la información pasada dentro de la etiqueta. Debiera ser **detalles** o algo similar y emplear la otra para pasar efectivamente datos de clientes.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la bienvenida y por la observación. En efecto, yo edité un poco el archivo xml para eliminar info confidencial y me quedó un poco desincronizado. Acabo de editar lo que indicas. Igualmente opté por copiar casi todo el xml porque a lo mejor, existe algo en el contexto general que es importante para precisar mejor las respuestas. El código general consiste en leer un archivo xml y generar un html que es mucho más liviano que el PDF que nos llega. Casi todo lo he resuelto basándome en lo publicado en el sitio, pero aún me quedan algunos detalles como éste. Gracias nuevamente.

Comment: He editado la respuesta. Espero que te sirva ambas soluciones planteadas. Saludos.

Comment: Estimado Adrián, en efecto, esta solución corre perfectamente.- Lamento no haber previsto el asunto de los enlaces externos pero ha sido muy interesante lo aprendido gracias a la colaboración de ustedes.-

Por otro lado, yo logré otra solución que voy a publicar también, utilizando los métodos de **xml.dom.minidom** y utilizando recursividad.- Quizás ahora lo importante sea quedarnos con la solución más eficiente para efectos prácticos o más elegante para efectos de aprendizaje.

Comment: Hola. Me alegro que se hayan solventado dudas. Si crees que la respuesta ayuda a solucionar lo que necesitas puedes marcarla como aceptada (visto verde). Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Usando de ejemplo el siguiente XML:

```
$ -> cat xml_example.xml 
   <Otros>
      <OtroTexto codigo="Pedido">0000098947</OtroTexto>
      <OtroTexto codigo="NombreCliente">letra por ¢8.000.000 del 25-01-2017pagan con cheque</OtroTexto>
      <OtroTexto codigo="Vendedor">75 AGENTE 75</OtroTexto>
      <OtroTexto codigo="Bodega">BODEGA PRINCIPAL</OtroTexto>
      <OtroTexto codigo="FechaEntrega">09/09/2020</OtroTexto>
      <OtroTexto codigo="LugarEntrega">759</OtroTexto>
   </Otros>
```

Podrías hacer uso del módulo `xml.etree.ElementTree`.

1. Importas el módulo:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
```

2. Cargas el fichero XML donde contienes todo. Con el método `getroot` obtienes el elemento "raíz":

```
root = ET.parse('xml_example.xml').getroot()
```

3. Recorres cada nodo cogiendo la etiqueta 'OtroTexto', coges cada elemento de este. Se usa el método `iter` para recorrer los elementos del "àrbol" XML y luego puedes acceder a su contenido mediante `text`.

```
for nodo in root.iter('OtroTexto'):
    for elemento in nodo.iter():
        print("Notas: ", elemento.text)
```

El **código** final sería:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root = ET.parse('xml_example.xml').getroot()

for nodo in root.iter('OtroTexto'):
    for elemento in nodo.iter():
        print("Notas: ", elemento.text)
```

Con **resultado**:

```
$ -> python3 xml_task.py 
Notas:  0000098947
Notas:  letra por ¢8.000.000 del 25-01-2017pagan con cheque
Notas:  75 AGENTE 75
Notas:  BODEGA PRINCIPAL
Notas:  09/09/2020
Notas:  759
```

Tienes más información de este módulo en el siguiente enlace: [xml.etree.ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html).

---

**EDITO**:

Si adicionalmente necesitas saber el valor del atributo (gracias @quevedo por la petición), podrías usar `attrib`:

Por ejemplo:

```
print(elemento.attrib)
```

**Imprime**:

```
{'codigo': 'Pedido'}
{'codigo': 'NombreCliente'}
{'codigo': 'Vendedor'}
{'codigo': 'Bodega'}
{'codigo': 'FechaEntrega'}
{'codigo': 'LugarEntrega'}
```

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root = ET.parse('xml_example.xml').getroot()

for nodo in root.iter('OtroTexto'):
    for elemento in nodo.iter():
        print(elemento.attrib['codigo'], ":", elemento.text)
```

En este caso ya sabes que codigo es la "key" del atributo por lo que puedes acceder fácilmente a él.

El **resultado** sería el siguiente:

```
Pedido : 0000098947
NombreCliente : letra por ¢8.000.000 del 25-01-2017pagan con cheque
Vendedor : 75 AGENTE 75
Bodega : BODEGA PRINCIPAL
FechaEntrega : 09/09/2020
LugarEntrega : 759
```

En caso de no saber que la key es `codigo`, podrías usar otro bucle para extraer la `key` de cada iteracción:

El **código** sería:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root = ET.parse('xml_example.xml').getroot()

for nodo in root.iter('OtroTexto'):
    for elemento in nodo.iter():
        for key in elemento.attrib:
            print(elemento.attrib[key], ":", elemento.text)
```

Y su **resultado**:

```
Pedido : 0000098947
NombreCliente : letra por ¢8.000.000 del 25-01-2017pagan con cheque
Vendedor : 75 AGENTE 75
Bodega : BODEGA PRINCIPAL
FechaEntrega : 09/09/2020
LugarEntrega : 759
```

---

**Edición final**:

Con el XML completo ahora es distinto. No solo tiene más etiquetas externas por lo que la accesibilidad a la etiqueta no es directa sino que también tienes un `namespace`:  `https://cdn.comprobanteselectronicos.go.cr/xml-schemas/v4.3/facturaElectronica}`

De hecho, al imprimir un nodo, por ejemplo, OtroTexto, aparecen los elementos de la siguiente forma:

```
<Element '{https://cdn.comprobanteselectronicos.go.cr/xml-schemas/v4.3/facturaElectronica}OtroTexto' at 0x7fda9283ac50>
```

Esta vez, haremos uso del método `findall`. De esta forma encontramos elementos "hijo" o "child" dentro de otras etiquetas.

1. Definimos el namespace:

```
ns = "{https://cdn.comprobanteselectronicos.go.cr/xml-schemas/v4.3/facturaElectronica}"
```

Y estavez cargamos raíz (digamos que es FacturaElectronica), bajamos una etiqueta `.//`, esto para acceder a Otros y encontramos todo lo que esté en {namespace}OtroTexto.

```
for nodo in root.findall(".//"+ns+"OtroTexto"):
```

**Código final**

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root = ET.parse('xml_example.xml').getroot()

ns = "{https://cdn.comprobanteselectronicos.go.cr/xml-schemas/v4.3/facturaElectronica}"


for nodo in root.findall(".//"+ns+"OtroTexto"):
    for elemento in nodo.iter():
        for key in elemento.attrib:
            print(elemento.attrib[key], ":", elemento.text)
```

**Resultado**:

```
Pedido : 0000098947
NombreCliente : letra por 8.000.000 del 25-01-2017 pagadero con cheque
Vendedor : 75 Agente 75
Bodega : BODEGA PRINCIPAL
FechaEntrega : 09/09/2020
LugarEntrega : 759
```

**Como alternativa**:

Podrías usar `regex` o expresiones regulares. Pero no es nada recomendable para parsear XML o incluso HTML. Además, lo mejor es que controles algo de regex para entenderlo y no solo resolver lo que necesitas. De igual forma, lo colocaré:

Podríamos usar la siguiente regex:

```
<OtroTexto codigo=\"(.*)\">(.*)<\/OtroTexto>
```

Podrías ver como funciona aqui: https://regex101.com/r/bWc1ND/1

- Utilizamos .* para seleccionar cualquier tipo de caracter que haya y los parentesis para subgrupos.

**Código final**:

```
import re

regex = re.compile("<OtroTexto codigo=\"(.*)\">(.*)<\/OtroTexto>")

# Abrimos el XML:
with open('xml_example.xml', 'r') as fichero:
    # Recorremos cada línea:
    for linea in fichero:
        # Guardamos la línea donde haya match, esto devuelve algo como:
        # <built-in method group of re.Match object at 0x7ff3c9e9d300>
        for match in re.finditer(regex, linea):
            # Imprimimos el primer grupo que capturamos con (.*) y el segundo grupo que capturamos con el otro (.*)
            print(match.group(1), ":", match.group(2))
```

**Resultado**:

```
Pedido : 0000098947
NombreCliente : letra por 8.000.000 del 25-01-2017 pagadero con cheque
Vendedor : 75 Agente 75
Bodega : BODEGA PRINCIPAL
FechaEntrega : 09/09/2020
LugarEntrega : 759
```

Comment: Por supuesto, luego puedes añadir cosas a tu código según necesites, como control de excepciones con `try`, `except`, `finally`.

Comment: Buena respuesta (+1). Hubiera sido un detalle valioso indicar cómo recuperar el atributo código dentro de las iteraciones.

Comment: Muchas gracias @quevedo por tu comentario. He añadido el cambio que comentaste. Saludos.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias Adrián, las ayudas en este sitio de verdad son invaluables. Estive revisando en detalle el módulo xml.etree.ElementTree. Por alguna razón, el código no funciona, no despliega nada. Sospecho que quizás por el contexto en general, pues se trata de un xml que no es típico sino que, corresponde a un documento electrónico. Si no fuera mucha molestia y pueden volver a echar un ojo, agradecería sobremanera. estoy adjuntando el xml completo .-

Comment: Hola. En teoría no debería haber problema. Estoy usando el mismo XML para extraer los datos que necesitas. Luego si ese XML tiene otra estructura exterior es distinto. Es decir, si hay más etiquetas. Entonces la pregunta cambiaría. Pero para el XML proporcionado funciona. Podrías añadir error también por si vemos algo más.

Comment: Saludos Adrián, en efecto, el problema lo tengo cuando la raíz <FacturaElectronica> incluye esas 4 declaraciones externas (xsi:schemaLocation, xmlns, xmlns:xsi, xmlns:ds)... Sin eso, el programa corre sin problemas. Pues toca seguir investigando. Agradezco mucho tu tiempo. Saludos.-

Comment: Hola. Te he dejado una nueva edición. Encontrarás todo luego de "Edición final:". He dejado la solución con el mismo uso de XML. Resulta que posee namespaces por lo que es distinto y además está dentro de otras etiquetas. Como alternativa, también te he dejado una solución basada en expresiones regulares. Espero haberte ayudado. Saludos.